# from data frame to generate a variable with a list of id-value pairs in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data table readin as a data frame like:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4
----------
  1     val1 val2  val3
  2     val2.1 val2.2 val2.3
  ...
  n     valn.1 valn.2 valn.3
```

From it, I want to use col1 and col2 to create a single variable like

```
var <- c('val1="1"', 'val2.1="2"', 'val3="3" ....)
```

I am new to R and could be a simple task.

Comment: can you explain how the column values become the key-value pairs?  where does 'val3="3"' come from?

Comment: If you could give us your input in valid syntax, that would help a lot too. `dput(your_data[1:4, ])` will give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 4 rows of your data.